# CakePHP: How can be displayed the inserted information into database?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following code in the controller:

```
    function add() {            
        if (!empty($this->data)) {              
            if ($this->Password->save($this->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('the password I_WANT_TO_DISPLAY_THE_INSERTED_PASSWORD_HERE was added');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
    }
}
```

The question is how can the inserted information be displayed in the view ?
A message something "The password XXX was addded into your database".
I think the data must be retrieved from the text-field. I don't know how to do this in cakePHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the saved data is always available from the `$this->data` array. You can use the syntax:

```
$this->data['Model']['field'];
```

For example if you saved the field `passwd` to the `passwords` table, it should be:

```
$this->Session->setFlash(
    'the password ' . $this->data['Password']['passwd'] . ' was added'
);
```